# SpriteKit how to get correct screen size

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, size, screen

I've tried

```
self.frame.size
self.view!.frame.size
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
```

None of them work.

How do I get the correct screen size for the device?

Comment: Where are you checking those properties? didMoveToView?

Comment: yup, over there. @0x0141E

Comment: How does `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size` not get you the correct size?  the reason self.frame and self.view.frame does not get you the correct size is because self.frame is the size of the scene, which is usually 600x600 and self.view.frame is the size of the view before autolayout get applied,  so it is probably 600x600 also

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use following swift code to get the screen size.

```
let displaySize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let displayWidth = displaySize.width
let displayHeight = displaySize.height
```

Comment: in Swift 4 it is `let displaySize: CGRect UIScreen.main.bounds`

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
let deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let deviceHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
```

And if you need to get the ratio so you can detect what device they are using, you can use the following for portrait mode or switch it for landscape mode.

```
let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = deviceHeight / deviceWidth
```

You can then check what ratio the device is to determine certain things.

```
if maxAspectRatio == (4 / 3) {
    //The ratio of an iphone 4S is 4:3
    print("The user is using an iPhone 4S or iPod 4th Generation.")
} else if maxAspectRatio >= 1.7 && maxAspectRatio <= 1.8 {
    //The ratio of these devices is 16:9
    print("The user is using an iPhone 5, 5S, 5C, 6, 6S, 6 Plus, 6S Plus, or iPod 5th Generation.)
} else {
    print("The user is using an iPad, iPad Mini, iPad Air, iPad Retina, or iPad Pro.")
}
```

If you want to get the correct view that the player can see, as in the bounding frame of the device's size, you can use the following [guide](https://github.com/jozemite/SpriteKit-Playable-Area).

Comment: broken link! =[